# jQuery animation skips first time

Tags: jquery, animation, hash, scroll, anchor

I have a simple script which slides the page up and down between two anchors:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.switch').each(function() {
        var self = this;
        if(self.hash) {
            $(self).click(function() {
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $(self.hash).offset().top
                }, 2000);
            });
         }
    });

});
```

However, the first time this function is called after opening the page, there is no animation and it just jumps instantly to the second anchor. It then resumes functioning properly.

Can anyone explain what is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: give Fiddle link so easy to understand.

Comment: first time remove click [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/Wja29/8/)

Comment: Did you just take Sheikh's code below and comment out the first part, including the "els" variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to scroll the first element on page load with `class name` `switch` and also want to add click event on each, if so then you can try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var els=$('a.switch');
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(els[0].hash).offset().top // els[0]=the first element, you can use the id too
    }, 2000);

    els.on('click', function(e) { // I've used 'on' and didn't use 'each'
        var self = this;
        if(self.hash) {    
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $(self.hash).offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wja29/7/).

Comment: That scrolls to the second anchor on page load. EDIT: Nevermind, els[0] had to be changed to els[1].

Comment: `els[0]` is for the first element but what doesn't work ? May be I din't understand at all, did you check the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wja29/7/).

Comment: To clarify, the `a.switch` is the button you click to scroll the page. Their (two of them) hrefs have hashtags to two anchors, one of which is visible on page load and another below the screen which scrolls up into view.

Comment: I should also explain in case it wasn't obvious from my demo in the comments above that the switches correspond to the opposite anchors they are next to. So on page load you see anchor A and the switch to scroll to anchor B. At anchor B is a switch to scroll back to anchor A.

Comment: So just to keep you up to date, I changed els[0] to els[1]. The page loads properly, but when the switch is clicked the URL changes but the page doesn't move. Upon clicking it again the page then scrolls down like normal.

Comment: To your above comment, what you had before was correct, it's just that the switches had to be swapped around. I can't figure out why mine doesn't function on the first click.

Comment: In fact, when I use the code you provided at the top exactly as-is, the animation doesn't even work, it just jumps between the anchors.

Comment: Can you post your html in your question ?

Comment: I posted a mockup: http://jsfiddle.net/B6tZA. Also, adding `e.preventDefault();` actually prevents the page from loading.

Comment: I think I know what the issue is. When the page first loads, the URL is `www.domain.com`. The switches are trying to look for `/index.html` in the URL. So once the switch is clicked, `/index.html#foo` is appended and then the second click can function properly. It's just a matter of redirecting to `www.domain.com/index.html`.

Comment: Glad to know that you got it :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help, even if it was just a silly oversight on my part.